# App Engine. HTTP ERROR: 503 on Gradle setup

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I've set up a new App Engine project in IntelliJ and Gradlefied it. Everything works fine until I try to add an HttpServlet. I've added a simple test class and the associated mapping in the web.xml file. When I go to run the development server I get several exceptions on startup followed by a 503 Error.

I'm guessing the fact it can't find my class is the root cause, but I don't understand why it can't find my class. Is that related to the *javax.servlet.UnavailableException*? The errors appear in the following order:

```
WARNING: EXCEPTION
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:main.webapp.Test2
```

....

```
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: main.webapp.Test2
```

....

```
WARNING: failed Test: java.lang.NullPointerException
Nov 12, 2014 2:07:56 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@34c8daa0{/,D:\Projects\WordBuzzIntegrated\build\classes\artifacts\app_engine_war_exploded}
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Test Class**

```
package main.webapp;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test2 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("BOO!");
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>main.webapp.Test2</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Root build.gradle**

```
....
project(":app-engine") {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'appengine'
}
....
```

**Module build.gradle**

```
appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    httpPort = 8080

    appcfg {
        email = 'xxxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx'
        passIn = true

        logs {
            severity = 1
            outputFile = file('mylogs.txt')
        }

        app {
            id = 'wordbuzzweb'
        }
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7

    dependencies {
        appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.15'
        providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually tracked this down. I needed to specify the source root in the build.gradle file as follows:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
    }
}
```

You can also specify a test folder if you're doing unit testing by adding

```
        test.java.srcDirs = ['test']
```

So my final build.gradle file for the module looks like this:

```
appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    httpPort = 8080

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            test.java.srcDirs = ['test']
        }
    }

    appcfg {
        email = 'xxxx.xxxxxx@xxxxx.com'
        passIn = true

        logs {
            severity = 1
            outputFile = file('mylogs.txt')
        }

        app {
            id = 'wordbuzzweb'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":comms")

        appengineSdk "com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:$appEngineVersion"
        compile "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:$appEngineVersion"
        compile "com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:$appEngineVersion"
        compile "com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:$appEngineVersion"

        compile "com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.1"
        compile group: "com.google.guava", name: "guava", version: "18.0"

        testCompile group: "junit", name: "junit", version: "4.11"
        testCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:$appEngineVersion"
        testCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:$appEngineVersion"
        testCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:$appEngineVersion"

        compile "javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5"
    }
}
```

You'll also need to add the following somewhere in your Gradle scripts to specify your app engine version.

```
ext.appEngineVersion = '1.9.15'
```